# UPDATE Statement for latitude and longitude based on address in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I am trying to load 20k addresses into a table where I geocode the user based on their address. Problem is there are already 200k of addresses we have already geocoded and I would like to just grab the long/lat from the same addresses I have already looked up.

So here is the query I am trying to get to work:

```
update
    SUBSCRIPTION S1 INNER JOIN SUBSCRIPTION S2 on S1.streetAddress = S2.streetAddress
    set S1.lat = S2.lat, S1.lon = S2.lon
where S2.lon IS NOT NULL AND S1.account_id = '388' and S2.account_id = '388';
```

You can see where I am trying to perform an update to a record that has no Long/Lat with the long/lat from another record in the same table that DOES have those values where the two addresses are exactly the same.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax in SQL Server is:

```
update s1
    set S1.lat = S2.lat,
        S1.lon = S2.lon
    from SUBSCRIPTION S1 join
         SUBSCRIPTION S2
         on S1.streetAddress = S2.streetAddress and
            S1.account_id = S2.account_id
    where S2.lon IS NOT NULL and
          S1.account_id = 388;
```

Notes:

- SQL Server uses `FROM` in the `UPDATE` statement.
- I removed the single quotes around `388`, assuming that it is really and integer.
- I moved the condition `S1.account_id = S2.account_id` into the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Updating only empty `LAT/LON` for table `WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION`

```
update S1
    set S1.lat = S2.lat
        , S1.lon = S2.lon
from  SUBSCRIPTION S1 
inner join SUBSCRIPTION S2 on S1.streetAddress = S2.streetAddress       
where coalesce(S1.lon, '') ='' and coalesce(S1.lat, '')=''
    and S1.account_id = '388' and S1.account_id = S2.account_id;
```